# TreeSet not sorting correctly

Tags: java

I have a self written comparator in java for comparing two name strings.

```
public class NamesSorter implements Comparator<EntityBean>{
    @Override
    public int compare(EntityBean a1, EntityBean a2) {
       return a1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(a2.getName());
    }
}
```

The main code using this sorter

> ```
> final Set<EntityBean> treeSet = new TreeSet<EntityBean>(new NamesSorter());
> final List<EntityBean> firstListToCompare=display.getAvailablePeople().getItems(); 
> final List<EntityBean> SecondListToCompare=display.getAvailablePeople().getItems(); 
> treeSet.addAll(firstListToCompare);
> treeSet.addAll(secondListToCompare);
> ```

When I run this code with the following input

> firstListToCompare amelia,george,megan
>
> secondListToCompare George Wash,Fang.

The result is

> amelia, Fang, george, megan, George Wash.

If I have an ignore case in the comparator why is it pushing George Wash to the end ?

the getName method.

> public String getName() {
>           return name;
>       }

Any name with a space between the two strings Like George Wash (which has a space between George and Wash) goes to the end of the list.. Why is that so ?

Comment: can you post the equals, hashcode and toString methods for that class?

Comment: Which class precisely is EntityBean? Is it your class or one from an external library?

Comment: EntityBean is my class. Declaration as public class EntityBean.

Comment: Your code is correct. But your result is wrong (may be in question) with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any funny characters / whitespace in the data? The poster's code has @Override and that doesn't give any errors. Unlike `equals()/ hashCode()`, there would be no Object method to default to -- so that's not what's happening.

**I think this may be a data error**.

Put some logging, or a breakpoint, in the Comparator method & see what's happening there.

```
public class NamesSorter implements Comparator<EntityBean>{
    @Override
    public int compare (EntityBean a1, EntityBean a2) {
       String name1 = a1.getName();
       String name2 = a2.getName();
       // let's try trimming them..
       name1 = name1.trim();
       name2 = name2.trim();
       int comp = name1. compareToIgnoreCase( name2);
       log.debug("  name CI comparison: "+name1+", "+name2+"="+comp);
       // System.out.println("  name CI comparison: "+name1+", "+name2+"="+comp);
       return comp;
    }
}
```

Logging is your friend.

Comment: I used logging and George Wash is being compared as greater than the rest which is weird.

Comment: Weird. Try trimming them -- we're looking for some kinda data error, data being modified after we read it, or (unlikely) a bug in compareToIgnoreCase().

Comment: The names with a space between them like George Wash get sorted to the end of the list. So for example I had dangie dang and George Wash the list would be  amelia,Fang,george,megan,dangie dang, George Wash.

Comment: Don't know why -- make a testcase for "megan" vs "George Wash", and try stepping thru String.compareToIgnoreCase(). Can you replicate it?

Comment: "megan".compareToIgnoreCase( "George Wash") == 6, on my system. I'd like to know what other funny business (\0 character? space? CR or LF?) are in your strings.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming your `getName()` is returning a `String`? Why not try adding `toString()` to `getName()`. So try...

```
public int compare(EntityBean a1, EntityBean a2) {
   return a1.getName().toString().compareToIgnoreCase(a2.getName().toString());
}
```

I just tried your code as below and it is giving me the correct output...

```
public class NamesSorter implements Comparator<Object>{
    public int compare(Object arg0, Object arg1) {
        return (arg0.toString()).compareToIgnoreCase(arg1.toString());
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Comp comp = new Comp();
    final Set<Object> treeSet = new TreeSet<Object>(comp.new NamesSorter());
    final List<Object> firstListToCompare = new ArrayList<Object>(); 
    firstListToCompare.add("amelia");
    firstListToCompare.add("george");
    firstListToCompare.add("megan");
    final List<Object> secondListToCompare = new ArrayList<Object>();
    secondListToCompare.add("George Wash");
    secondListToCompare.add("Fang");

    treeSet.addAll(firstListToCompare);
    treeSet.addAll(secondListToCompare);
    for (Iterator<Object> iter = treeSet.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
        System.out.println((String) iter.next());
    }
}
```

The result...

```
amelia
Fang
george
George Wash
megan
```

Comment: +1. more sorter `List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList("amelia", "george", "megan");` and `System.out.println(treeSet);`